# autotest ignore some files under "integration" directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, autotest

I am using Capybara and rspec for integration testing.
I have created 2 files that I put under the spec/integration folder.

```
/spec/integration/
                 login_integration_spec.rb
                 registration_integration_spec.rb
```

Autotest is also configured to take in effect the changes made in the files from this folder

```
  autotest.add_mapping(%r%^spec/(integration)/.*rb$%) { |filename, _|
    filename
  }
```

The problem is that only the test file "registration_integration_spec.rb" is executed.
Do you know how I can tell autotest to take in consideration the whole directory?

Thank you.

Comment: I think autotest is automatically configured to ignore the log directory. autotest must be ignoring all the: log* files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, the problem was my autotest config file.
I had this:

```
Autotest.add_hook :initialize do |autotest|
  %w{.git .svn .hg .DS_Store ._* vendor tmp log doc}.each do |exception|
    autotest.add_exception(exception)
  end
end
```

I just removed the log folder from the exceptions list.